# How to work within an environment in R?

Tags: r

I couldn't find anything about how to do this. I want to perform a set of analyses in R within a separate environment. For example:

```
n.e <- new.env()
n.e$df <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 6,]
n.e$avg_mpg <- mean(n.e$df$mpg)
n.e$median_qsec <- median(n.e$df$qsec)
```

The actual calculations aren't important, but the crux is that it's cumbersome starting everything with `n.e$`. If there were some way to work exclusively in the environment `n.e`, such as:

```
n.e <- new.env()
workwithinenvironment(n.e){
  df <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 6,]
  avg_mpg <- mean(df$mpg)
  median_qsec <- median(df$qsec)
}
```

Which would end with the same result, but I could do without writing `n.e$` over and over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use `with()`, which (as noted on its help page) will accept an environment as its first argument.

```
n.e <- new.env()
with(n.e, {
     df <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 6,]
     avg_mpg <- mean(df$mpg)
     median_qsec <- median(df$qsec)
})

## Check that it works
ls(n.e)
## [1] "avg_mpg"     "df"          "median_qsec"
n.e$avg_mpg
## [1] 19.74286
```